# Django admin panel works but main page gives me a 404

Tags: django, debian, django-urls, django-settings

I'm brand new to Django and Python. I've only done php.

It took me three tries, but I've almost Django installed correctly. I followed the tutorial on installing it, and it worked. So I enabled the admin, panel, and set up mysql.

The admin panel works, and I've got my static folder so it has all of the css as well. But when I go to the main page I get this 404. (My project is called *firstweb*) So whenI go into firstweb there is a 404, but firstweb/admin works.

```
Using the URLconf defined in firstweb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

 1.   ^admin/

The current URL, firstweb/, didn't match any of these.
```

And I'm confused by the whole runserver thing. Is that some other little server other than my Apache? Why do I need to start it every time?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'firstweb.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^firstweb/', include('firstweb.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Admin is not enabled by default for django pre 1.5  follow the steps here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#overview

Comment: `runserver` is just for local development, not for running your site in production.

Comment: Karth, the admin panel is enabled and works. I mentioned that. The main page has the 404. The admin has zero problems.

Comment: @gregor - Depending on the ordering of your urls.py file, it may pick up the individual admin pages but not the main page. Can you show your urls file? The ordering can be important.

Comment: @Joseph, Added it to the OP above.

Comment: Thanks, looks like since that's the only ting in your urlpatterns it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So what is going to go there?  I mean what url will I add?

Comment: I mean in any tutorial I've seen there wasn't a 404 error it just showed the default page. Is something wrong? Do I need to add a url?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your url conf does not include any url pattern for any other pages accept the admin.

If you want the root url to display a page, uncomment this line

```
url(r'^$', 'firstweb.views.home', name='home'),
```

And then make sure that in firstweb/views.py you have a view function called 'home', which I assume is part of the tutorial.